# Mouse clicking in c# .NET service

Tags: c#, windows-services, mouse

I wrote small windows service responsible for mouse clicking in 30 seconds interval. I have a problem with simulate mouse clicking.
I tried this code:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static extern void mouse_event(long dwFlags, long dx, long dy, long cButtons, long dwExtraInfo);

        private const int MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN = 0x02;
        private const int MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP = 0x04;
        private const int MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN = 0x08;
        private const int MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP = 0x10;

        public static void DoMouseClick()
        {

            mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN | MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        }
```

and it didn't click I also tried use InputSimulator library and it didn't work too. 
I found a lot of solutions but it working for WPF application.
Is it possible to simulate mouse clicking in windows service?

Comment: you can try to set the "interact with desktop" option for windows service. But it is quite strange and unusual way to send mouse clicks from the windows service. Would you try to use system tray icon and hide application from task bar ? This will work like ordinary windows application and will do mouse events tricks

Comment: @oleksa I think that it is a good idea, thank you, I will try it.